# When is the next Transit of Venus from Mars?

Tags: mars, venus

When will the next transfer of Venus take place from the perspective of Mars?
Will the next human to view one be a Martian?

Comment: I think that Astronomy SE is a better place for this question. See for example [When will the next transit of Earth be visible from Mars? Was the last one really on May 11, 1984?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26177/7982) and [Why do transits of Earth across the Sun seen from Mars follow a pattern of occurring after 26, 79 then 100 years?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32989/7982) and [How will planets behave in the night sky as seen by Mars colonists?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26166/7982)

Comment: and [How would astronomical seeing on Mars differ from that on Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28159/7982), but it certainly is not off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

[Infogalactic.com](https://infogalactic.com/info/Transit_of_Venus_from_Mars) says Venus will transit from Mars on August 19, 2030.  So it may be a bit soon to have an established human colony on Mars.  But a human explorer on Mars or a space probe might catch it.

The next Earth transit from Mars is [November 10, 2084](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_of_Earth_from_Mars), by which time human Martians would be more likely.